# | htaccess | Codeigniter seleccionar idioma |

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

Utilizo codeigniter como framework, no es una página web creada por mi, lo que me gustaría saber, es si es posible redirigir a una persona a su idioma cuando entre a la página web.

El asunto, es que para cambiar de idioma, la página web utiliza esto:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setLanguage('español', this)" class="current_language">
  </a>
```

Entonces, no encuentro la manera de que la web redirija al usuario cuando entre a su idioma correspondiente, porque la web esta utilizando una función pública que esta ubicada en el handler interno de la web y esta función lo que hace es actualizar con un query la base de datos y poner el idioma en la base de datos, 
entonces no es una URL, mi idea era haber utilizado este htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/de/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/nl/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/fr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://mysite.com/es/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|de|nl|fr|es)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Pero vamos, al no haber una ruta url que cambie el idioma, no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo y este .htaccess no sirve.

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Si el lenguaje no está como parámetro (GET o POST), y no está dentro de un header, no hay nada que puedas hacer desde el .htaccess (al menos no sin entrar en complicaciones mayores con CGIs)... La única forma sería desde código, por lo que podrías usar el .htaccess que tenés en la pregunta (aunque no recomendaría un 301 en la redirección, por si cambia de lenguaje), y armar la lógica para que lea/escriba en la base de datos desde el index.php.... Más que eso es imposible responder... ¿Podrías publicar el código de la función `setLanguage()`?

Comment: Este es el código de setLanguage()

    public function setLanguage($userId, $language)
    {
        $this->connection->query("UPDATE account_data SET language = ? WHERE id = ?", array($language, $userId));
    }

Comment: entonces claramente se está manejando todo por base de datos, por lo que no importa cuál sea el `Accept-Language` definido en el navegador, ni qué parámetros tengas. Lo único que podrías hacer es manejarte con la base de datos desde tu script, y redireccionar desde ahí, pero no desde el .htaccess.

Comment: Vale Mariano muchas gracias por la respuesta :-D